# Flask regex search, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group', but still get the captured string

Tags: python, regex, heroku, flask

I was trying to get JSON at [this site](https://www.lazada.co.id/logitech-official-store/?langFlag=id&q=All-Products&from=wangpu&pageTypeId=2) with this Flask code:

```
def main():
    link = "https://www.lazada.co.id/logitech-official-store/?langFlag=id&q=All-Products&from=wangpu&pageTypeId=2"
    result = re.search(r'pageData=(.+)<', requests.get(link).text)
    result = result.group(1)
    result = json.loads(result)
    listItems = result["mods"]["listItems"]
    return render_template('index.html', listItems=listItems)
```

Then i got the following error:

```
File "app.py", line 18, in main
    result = result.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The strange thing is that it still get the result and able to render the template. But when i deploy it to Heroku, the page won't display. It says "Internal Server Error" and showing the above Error in the log. So i thought to check whether i really got the result or not by modifying the code into this:

```
def main():
    link = "https://www.lazada.co.id/logitech-official-store/?langFlag=id&q=All-Products&from=wangpu&pageTypeId=2"
    result = re.search(r'pageData=(.+)<', requests.get(link).text)
    if result:
        result = result.group(1)
        result = json.loads(result)
        listItems = result["mods"]["listItems"]
        return render_template('index.html', listItems=listItems)
    else:
        return "failed"
```

When running locally, it worked fine, able to render the template and showing no error. But when i deploy it to Heroku, it always got no result and showing the "failed" string.
I don't understand this strange behavior. I want to get my code work at Heroku. Did i miss something here?

Comment: you may want to check what's being returned in requests.get(link).text

Comment: @user3713719 oh right, the site blocked my request. strange this is i still being able to get the data by running it locally. thanks for telling me, i think i should close this thread